# How to change/set background color of a single row in a datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

How can I change the background color of a single row in a datagrid using c#?

Comment: conditional formatting? for example: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/88ef4274-0712-4dcf-90dd-4ae82ce3a63d/wpf-datagrid-conditional-formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Property }" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FAFAFA" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

C#:

```
private void MarkRowAsDone(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var context = new Context())
        {
            try
            {
                //If you have set a ID, get that ID to do a "select"-statement
                var row = context.CLASS.Find(selectedItem.Id);
                row.Done = true;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the item-template's Background property to the data-item's property. The code above was used for a List-item template:
`XAML
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel x:Name="itemBlock">
            ...
        </StackPanel>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsIncluded}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="itemBlock" Value="#DDDCAB"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsIncluded}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="itemBlock" Value="Transparent"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>`